# Check if toggle class active and then don't toggle

Tags: jquery

I have a toggle that is working. Both the h4 and a sidebar link, using an anchor, toggle the div, with this:

```
$(".trigger_papers").click(function(){
    $('h4.trigger_papers').toggleClass("active");
    $('#papers').toggleClass("active").slideToggle("slow");
    //return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
})
```

However, when the div is already open, and the sidebar link for it is clicked, then the page scrolls to the toggled div and closes it. Because its toggling. I want, if the sidebar link is clicked, for the toggle class to be checked and if it is already active, don't toggle. I tried this:

```
$(".trigger_papers").click(function(){
    $('h4.trigger_papers').toggleClass("active");
    if($('h4.trigger_papers').hasClass('active'){
        $('#papers');
    }else{
        $('#papers').toggleClass("active").slideToggle("slow");
        }
    //return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
})
```

And it just made all the div's toggled to active. What am I doing wrong? I still want the h4 to be able to toggle, regardless of class.

Here is my HTML for toggling the div:

```
<h4 class="trigger_papers dark_grey">
<a href="#">Papers and Publications</a></h4>
<div class="toggle_container3" id="papers"> 
--- content ---
</div>
```

Here is my HTML for the side bar link:

```
  <li><a href="#papers" class="trigger_papers" title="">Papers and Publications</a></li>
```

Comment: please include your html or https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: So why are you toggling first and then checking? Is that intended or is that the issue?

Comment: Need to see html preferably in a fiddle. But sounds like you need to us .addClass() instead of .toggleClass() if you don't want to remove it. Or if you want to remove it only in certain cases.

Comment: There is also a `Add Code Snippet` button here in the editor which is pretty similar to fiddles.

Comment: HTML added. @PeterKA I was toggling first because that was what I started with, simply toggling the divs open or closed by clicking on the h4. But then I had to add a sidebar nav that would go to and open the div, in addition to the h4 toggling the div. I will try changing the order and play with some if/thens, using .addClass()